# Pattern match using regexp_extract_all

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to build a array from this string and need help with pattern on `regexp_extract_all`.

Here is my input string contains keyword value pairs

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE p_JSON  STRING DEFAULT """
      {
        "instances": [{
        "LT_20MN_SalesContrctCnt": 388.0, 
        "Pyramid_Index": '', 
        "MARKET": "'Growth Markets','Europe'", 
        "SERVICE_DIM": "'S&C','F&M'",
        "SG_MD": "'All Service Group'"
      }]}
    """;

 SELECT split(x,":")[OFFSET(0)] as keyword, split(x,":")[OFFSET(1)] keyword_value
      FROM  unnest(split(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(p_JSON, '$.instances'),r'([\'\"\[\]{}])', ''))) as x  
END;
```

The above SQL is failing at SPLIT due to , with in the data.

All I am trying to do here is build a two columns Keyword and value.

The idea here is if I can extract each row using  `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` with out the last "," then I should be able to split into keyword and keyword_value columns.  Btw the names or number of keywords/values are not fixed.

Intended output from `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`:

```
"LT_20MN_SalesContrctCnt": 388.0  
"Pyramid_Index": ''
"MARKET": "'Growth Markets','Europe'"
"SERVICE_DIM": "'S&C','F&M'"  
"SG_MD": "'All Service Group'"
```

Appreciate if you can suggest a better way to handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: google says `regexp_extract_all` is a SQL thing, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/regexp_extract_all. Can you specify more details about the sql dialect (and add it as tag to the question), and especially what the array should look like? I don't understand how your example should be split into an array. Each key value pair like `"...": "..."`  as an array element or like [key, value, key, value, ..]?

Comment: I am trying to run it under bigquery

Comment: Then please correct your tags, because SQL Server is not bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample data, I just added an extra `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace `,"` to `@"` so we can avoid splitting using `,`. See approach below:

```
SELECT 
  SPLIT(arr,":")[OFFSET(0)] as keyword,
  SPLIT(arr,":")[OFFSET(1)] as keyword_value,
FROM sample_data,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(p_JSON, '$.instances'),r'[\[\]{}]',''),r',"','@"'),'@')) arr
```

Output:

[image]